# What is the use and meaning of Mine in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have some code with references like the following:

```
Mine.PlaySound(Mine.Sounds.Restart)
```

Playsound() is a sub in another vb file (and another class - Friend Class MyCode), and Sounds is an enumeration in that file and class. Both are declared public, and clearly the Mine prefix allows the code above to access the sub and enumeration (removing Mine causes access errors).

It doesn't exist in the MyCode.vb file at all, so it's not an alias or direct reference; it has to be a language keyword. But I can't find mention of the Mine keyword anywhere in VB.Net documentation. Can someone help me understand how to use this?

Comment: There [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/) `My`, there isn't `Mine`. Look harder. Is that a module, namespace or project name?

Comment: Thank you, GSerg. I found it. It's an instance of MyCode class.

Comment: Just to make sure, before wondering what it is, did you put the caret inside the word `Mine` and press F12?